# How to use all voices available?

Tags: c#, windows-10, speechsynthesizer

I am using this command to list available voices

```
private static SpeechSynthesizer sprecher;

...

sprecher = new SpeechSynthesizer();

...

private static List<VoiceInfo> GetInstalledVoices()
{
    var listOfVoiceInfo = from voice
                          in sprecher.GetInstalledVoices()
                          select voice.VoiceInfo;

    return listOfVoiceInfo.ToList<VoiceInfo>();
}
```

I get only 4 different voices (Hedda, Hazel, David and Zira) yet windows itself shows many more speakers.

[image]

Therefore I only get the "-Desktop"-voices. How do I access the other speakers via c#?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I couldn't get it to work locally, I tried doing the registry copy mentioned here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20014a3c-8d30-44b6-867a-3a67f0a43071/how-to-set-the-voice-of-speechsynthesizer-to-an-arabic-voice-?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Comment: @hellyale You were spot on. Using this registry copy I solved it. Maybe you need to export it, like I did? Export the whole `Token` Directory of `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices` to a file. Replace every `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens` with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens` in the file and run the file(I removed the voices I alread have before). Change CPU to `x64`. Enjoy.

Comment: Ok, I am going to undelete and add those details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit 2: OP got it to work by using export instead of command line copying

> Export the whole Token Directory of Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices to a file. Replace every HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens in the file and run the file(I removed the voices I already had before).

On the [following thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20014a3c-8d30-44b6-867a-3a67f0a43071/how-to-set-the-voice-of-speechsynthesizer-to-an-arabic-voice-?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) a MSDN user, A.Kelany, asks a similar question, where he is only getting two voices from the `GetInstalledVoices` method.

He said he was able to fix this by doing the following :

> I managed to get it to work in a test project by doing the following :
>   I opened the registry and noticed that there is a node :
>   Quote:
>   **Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices**
>
> which contained the voices that appear in the application GetInstalledVoices method
>
> and there is another node :
>
> Quote:
>   **Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices**
>
> that contained all the voices including the ones don't appear in the  aforementioned method,
>
> So I copied one of the voices from the second node to the first node
>   and it worked!

He also states that he could not build on `Any CPU` after this change, and had to change the build type to `x64`

Comment: Wow6432Node is where 32-bit registry entries are located on 64-bit windows.  You need to copy these for it to work correctly on Any CPU.  Just follow the same process of exporting the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices entries to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\SPEECH\Voices.

Comment: Some voices did not show up, but changing to x64 fixed issue